# Can I get current config file from log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to get current config file from C#

Then I was found code to get current log file from this code

```
  var rootAppender =   ((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root
        .Appenders.OfType<FileAppender>().FirstOrDefault();

  string filename = rootAppender != null ? rootAppender.File : string.Empty;
```

So It return log Path  but I want current in used config file (ex. C:\TestLog\WriteLog.log4net)

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you need? If you can provide some more context around the problem you're trying to solve it may be easier to help you.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to know the name and location of the file that was used to configure log4net.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at [the source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/Config/XmlConfigurator.cs?view=markup) suggests this isn't possible, but if you're prepared to do a custom build of log4net it looks straightforward, maybe add the path to `ILoggerRepository` and populate it in `InternalConfigure(ILoggerRepository repository, FileInfo configFile)`